# Imageview animation from top to above marker

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps

I have one fragment. In that Google map is showing. In the google map I have added markers based on API response.

I need to show dynamic image views(as number of markers available) with top to bottom animation(till above marker). Need to load the image from the drawable in the dynamic image view.

For example there are three latitude and longitude and three markers based on latitude and longitude.

So I want to animate dynamic image view from top of the screen  to the above marker position.

Please help me with this in Kotlin.
Thanks in advance.